# How to only show second and third tab when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I would like the second and third tab to only be visible when clicked upon. Could someone look at the below code and help me figure out how this can be achieved?  Right now, the three tabs show by default, until one of the tabs is clicked upon, after which only the selected tab is shown.

Many thanks!

```
<div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 
'General')"><span size="4" style="font-size: small;"><span color="grey" 
style="color: grey;"><b>General</b></span></span></button> <button 
class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Product Specifications')"><span 
size="4" style="font-size: small;"><span color="grey" style="color: grey;">
<b>Product Specifications</b></span></span></button><button class="tablinks" 
onclick="openCity(event, 'Guarantee')"><span size="4" style="font-size: 
small;"><span color="grey" style="color: grey;"><b>Guarantee</b></span>
</span></button></div>
<div id="General" class="tabcontent">
CONTENT
</div>
<div id="Product Specifications" class="tabcontent">
CONTENT
</div>
<div id="Guarantee" class="tabcontent">
CONTENT
</div>

<script>// <![CDATA[
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", 
 "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that 
opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you used W3Schools as a template. Why not just use their original template and change the styling and content to your liking? The link is below.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

Comment: Hi, I did indeed used the W3S template. However the content of the three tabs are show by default when using the code. Only when one is selected, the content of the other tabs is hidden.  I am not sure why though..

Comment: @Maximus000 I don't get what are you saying, are you talking about your code of W3S's code?

Comment: I did not change anything to the code of W3S, i.e. my code is the same as the W3S's code example

Comment: @Maximus000 Maybe try using their default css